# unable to set Environment Variable in MacOSX

Tags: macos, bash, command-line

I am trying to add Racket's `bin` to my list of environment/path variables.

Here is the location of Racket's bin folder:

```
/Applications/Racket/bin
```

Here is what I have added to my `.bash_profile` file:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Racket/bin
```

Here is the Path output from set:

```
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Applications/Racket/bin
```

However, when I run `./racket`, I still get:

```
-bash: ./racket: No such file or directory
```

I am able to run `./racket` from Racket's `bin` directory (meaning that it probably isn't a 32- *v* 64-bit issue).

Answer (score 4):

> However, when I run ./racket, I still get a "-bash: ./racket: No such
>   file or directory"

Run it like this instead:

```
racket
```

When you run `./racket` it means run an executable racket from your **current directory**.

Comment: If it works for you then pls accept the answer (by clicking right click) whenever you can :)